# Commutator of spacetime translation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator

In Srednicki's textbook [Quantum Field Theory](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), eq. (95.7) reads:

\begin{equation}
[\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*}), P^{\mu}] = -i\partial^{\mu}\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*}).
\end{equation}

where $\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*})$ is a superfield and $P^{\mu}$ is a generator of the Poincare group.

I don't quite understand this equation. To my understanding, the left-hand side is a commutator, so it should be
\begin{equation}
[\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*}), P^{\mu}] = i\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*})\partial^{\mu} -i\partial^{\mu}\Phi (x, \theta, \theta^{*}).
\end{equation}
Why is the first term on the right-hand side missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember! Those are operators, and as such they act on some state $\varphi$. The second term, when operating on this $\varphi$, includes in fact two components

$$P_{\mu}(\Phi\varphi)=(P_{\mu}\Phi)\varphi+\Phi(P_{\mu}\varphi)$$

Put this back into the commutator to get your answer.